# Vlookup data greater than 0 only from two columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

On my first tab, I need to return the data from the second tab, columns A,B and C; only when the value of column A is greater than 0. I have pics to send but don't see a way to upload them. Currently using this formula, but have been unable to expand on it to get what I need.

```
=VLOOKUP('MSA Units'!A4, 'MSA Units'!A4:C882,1,FALSE)
```

I have also tried various forms of INDEX and MATCH arguments with no good results.

HERE IS REVISED LINK TO IMAGES: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxp6p.jpg

Comment: Post a link to the pictures (imgur.com) and someone will embed them in your post for you. New users can't upload pictures.

Comment: You image makes no sense as to what you want.... Also I don't understand your formula `=VLOOKUP('MSA Units'!A4, 'MSA Units'!A4:C882,1,FALSE)`, that makes no sense... Please explain what it is you want....

Comment: John, in the second image, (which is my second tab of the worksheet) if column A is greater than 0; then I need it to pull the information from columns A, B and C of that row and place them into first tab, column A

Comment: In the second tab of you file, is column A a static number (like an ID) or is it a quantity that changes often?

Comment: Cole, it is a qty that will change. This number is keyed at whatever qty of the particular units the men did that day or week.

Comment: there are over 850 units in the array on this sheet

Comment: @Resez - last question, the Unit ID, that one is unique for each line?

Comment: yes Cole, the Unit ID is unique for each line

Answer (score 0):

Filter `MSA Units` and for columnA select all other than (Blanks). Copy ColumnsA:C of what remains visible into `Daily Report Coversheet`.

Comment: We just want the field guys to be able to enter the qty they have and all the info to pull over for them. They are not going to filter and copy and paste. However, we could do that once we receive the data entry from the field.